# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm totally new to programming. I'm currently trying to create the WPF App that will calculate the Square Root etc. of the number1. I have a problem with using a method that calculates the square root (and not only). I got an error saying:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'MainWindow.RadioBT_Root2_Checked(object, RoutedEventArgs)'

This error occurs on RadioBT_Root3_Checked and RadioBT_Root4_Checked, because I've got 3 methods.

Its code is CS7036. What am i doing bad? I was searching so much but I can't find it (or I can't search).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Examples {
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow: Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    double number1;
    double number2;
    double result;

    private void TXB_1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {

    }

    private void TXB_2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {

    }

    private void BT_Potegowanie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      try {
        number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
        number2 = double.Parse(TXB_2.Text);
        result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);

        MessageBox.Show("WYNIK: " + result.ToString());

      } catch (Exception) {
        MessageBox.Show("Wystąpił błąd.", "Błąd", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
      }
    }

    public void BT_Root_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      if (RadioBT_Root2_Checked()) ///CS7036
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());

      if (RadioBT_Root3_Checked()) ///CS7036
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());

      if (RadioBT_Root4_Checked()) ///CS7036
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
    }

    public void RadioBT_Root2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
      result = Math.Sqrt(number1);
    }

    public void RadioBT_Root3_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
      number2 = (1 / 3.0);
      result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
    }

    public void RadioBT_Root4_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
      number2 = (1 / 4.0);
      result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: I've done what Ed Plunkett sugested and I've now another problem. It's XAML related (I think). I also found that i might need place '?? false' in some places. The error list says: 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'RadioBT_Root4_Checked' and no extension method 'RadioBT_Root4_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Examples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TXB_1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChan`enter code here`gedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TXB_2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void BT_Root_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double number1 = 0;
            double number2 = 0;
            double result = 0;

            if (RadioBT_Root2.IsChecked ?? false)    ///CS0266
            {
                number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
                result = Math.Sqrt(number1);
            }
            else if (RadioBT_Root3.IsChecked ?? false)   ///CS0266
            {
                number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
                number2 = (1 / 3.0);
                result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
            }
            else if (RadioBT_Root4.IsChecked ?? false)   ///CS0266
            {
                number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
                number2 = (1 / 4.0);
                result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
        }       
    }
```

My XAML code:

```html
<Window x:Class="Examples.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Examples"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="First number&#xD;&#xA;&#xA;First number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="117" Height="31" FontSize="15"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TXB_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="132,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="15" TextChanged="TXB_1_TextChanged"/>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Second number&#xD;&#xA;&#xA;Second number&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Height="30" FontSize="15"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TXB_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="132,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TXB_2_TextChanged" FontSize="15"/>
        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="0,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517"/>
        <Button x:Name="BT_Root" Content="ROOT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Height="48" FontSize="16" Click="BT_Root_Click"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBT_Root2" Content="Root2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioBT_Root2_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBT_Root3" Content="Root3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioBT_Root3_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBT_Root4" Content="Root4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioBT_Root4_Checked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I aslo tried changing 'Checked="RadioBT_Root4_Checked"/>' to 'Checked="RadioBT_Root4.IsChecked"/>'. It says 'Error Checked="RadioBT_Root2.IsChecked" is not valid. 'RadioBT_Root2.IsChecked' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.'

Comment: Please post your XAML too

Comment: You should stop here and first read and understand a book about programming C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your event handlers -- for example, `RadioBT_Root2_Checked` -- with no parameters, even though they require two parameters. You're also acting like they "return" `bool`, even though they "return" nothing.

What does "return" mean? `1 + 3` returns `4`:

```
int x = 1 + 3;
```

Now `x` is equal to 4.

Functions can return values:

```
public bool GreaterThan(int x, int y) { return x > y; }
```

Use it like this:

```
if (GreaterThan(10, 9))
{
    MessageBox.Show("10 is greater than 9");
}
```

But I think you don't really want to call those methods. I think this is what you want:

When Root is clicked, I think you want to find out which checkbox the user clicked, and then show that result. The results are calculated *when* the checkboxes are checked; those functions are the event handlers. To find out IF each checkbox is checked, look at the checkbox object -- using the name you gave it -- and look at its `IsChecked` property.

Like so:

```
public void BT_Root_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (RadioBT_Root2.IsChecked)
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
    else if (RadioBT_Root3.IsChecked)
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
    else if (RadioBT_Root4.IsChecked)
        MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
}
```

Except, look at those if statements: All three are doing the same thing. You can simplify further:

```
public void BT_Root_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
}
```

But here's a better way:

```
public void BT_Root_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    double number1 = 0;
    double number2 = 0;
    double result = 0;

    if (RadioBT_Root2.IsChecked)
    {
        number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
        result = Math.Sqrt(number1);
    }
    else if (RadioBT_Root3.IsChecked)
    {
        number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
        number2 = (1 / 3.0);
        result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
    }
    else if (RadioBT_Root4.IsChecked)
    {
        number1 = double.Parse(TXB_1.Text);
        number2 = (1 / 4.0);
        result = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
}
```

You don't need `result`, `number`, and `number2` to be class members, and you don't need those `*_Checked` event handlers at all.